# Why Proxy can't catch the set in the arrow function

Tags: javascript

```js
class O {
  count = 0;
  add = () => {
    this.count++;
  };
}

const o = new O();
const po = new Proxy(o, {
  set(t, k, v, r) {
    console.log("set", k, v);
    return true;
  },
});

po.add();
console.assert(po.count === 1);
```

When calling `add`, the value is changed correctly, but why the set hook does not respond

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set trap will only be entered into when something tries to assign to a property of the *proxy*. But your `o` class tries to assign to a property of `this`, where `this` is the *instance*, not the Proxy:

```
  add = () => {
    this.count++;
  };
```

Note that these class fields are equivalent to doing

```
class O {
  constructor() {
    this.count = 0;
    this.add = () => {
      this.count++;
    };
  }
}
```

so `this` always refers to the instance, rather than the proxy.

If you use a method or function instead, the calling context will be preserved, rather than always being the instance, and the `.add` being called from the Proxy will result in `this` being the Proxy in such cases:

```js
class O {
  count = 0;
  add() {
    this.count++;
  };
}

const o = new O();
const po = new Proxy(o, {
  set(t, k, v, r) {
    console.log("set", k, v);
    return true;
  },
});

po.add();
console.log(po.count === 1);
```